# Servicenow Working with ACLs and Business Rules to read Incident table

Tags: acl, business-rules, servicenow

I am currently working on a role called "read_incident" which should allow EES Users read the incidents of their assignment group.

Therefor I did the following:

- created a role "read_incident"
- assigned the role to group "Service Desk"
- created a user "Denis" and added him to the "Service Desk" group
- modified the query incident Business rule using an addorcondition to include my "read_incident" role to read incidents. (now you either have the "itil role", or the "read_incident" role to read incidents.
- created an ACL with dynamic filter to read incidents if the assignment group is one of my groups.

Now I created a homepage using a gauge of a list report of incidents which are assigned to "service desk" group.

As admin I can see all the incidents of course. But when I impersonate "Denis", the incident list reports the following "**No records to display**"

So nothing is blocking me from reading incidents, but somehow there is no Data match.
I tried creating a new incident and assign it to the "service desk" but still this incident isn't visible for the user "Denis".

What I know until now:
- Business rule is 100% working, because no "data is blocked" - I can query the incident table

The Business rule:

```
if (!gs.hasRole("itil").addOrCondition(!gs.hasRole("read_incident") && gs.isInteractive()) {
  var u = gs.getUserID();
  var qc = current.addQuery("caller_id", u).addOrCondition("opened_by", u).addOrCondition("watch_list", "CONTAINS", u);
  gs.print("query restricted to user: " + u);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the script of the business rule?

Comment: Hello Joey, sure, I added my rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your business rule is not correct: *gs.hasRole()* method returns true or false, you cannot use the method *addOrCondition()* there. There is also an error in your *if* sentence, it is needed another ")" at the end of the condition.

Try the following:

**Business Rule Condition**

```
(!gs.hasRole("itil") || !gs.hasRole("read_incident")) && gs.isInteractive()
```

**Script**

```
(function executeRule(current, previous /*null when async*/) {

    var u = gs.getUserID();
    current.addQuery("caller_id", u).addOrCondition("opened_by", u).addOrCondition("watch_list", "CONTAINS", u);

})(current, previous);
```

It is better to use the Condition field when possible, it improves the performance. I'm not sure if the business rule script meets your needs, I think you should check if the user is member of the current assignment_group, right?